# KSOD problems, shell.dll

Tags: windows-7, shell, black-screen-of-death

When i was using the Theme Manager, i tried to install a theme onto a windows 7 enterprise 32-bit laptop and when i restarted computer after the logo screen it went to the KSOD and had an error pop up saying shell.dll is corrupt or something and i cant do anything. i probably shouldnt be laying around with that stuff but is there any way i can fix it?
I cant alt+ctrl+del it tried all modes still not working.
Help?

Comment: Did you use some sort of UXTheme patcher?

Answer (score 1):

boot from the [Windows 7 DVD or Windows Recovery Environment (F8), run the command prompt](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-7-recovery-environment-command-prompt/) and run this:

```
sfc /SCANNOW /OFFBOOTDIR=c:\ /OFFWINDIR=c:\windows
```

Replace `C:` with the drive letter where you installed Windows.